# I am having massive trouble setting up a cron job in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

Sorry if this has already been answered, but I have looked around and have been unable to find the help, I've followed countless tutorials etc, just can't get my head around it.

So I have a Magento 2.1.0 website running, but It needs the standard Magento cron jobs that do the The following tasks.

Catalog Price rules
Sending Newsletters
Generating Google Sitemaps
Customer Alerts/Notifications (product price change, product back to stock)
Automatic updating of currency rates
Scheduled DB logs cleanup

However, when I try via SSH I get permission error when entering this command, so am unable to progress further, despite using the system username that has the valid permissions:

```
*crontab -u magento_user -e*
```

So I have tried doing it via plesk, but I get a "No such file exists error" when using this command (using my details obviously):

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Apparently Magento.cron.log doesn't exist.

I'm stuck right now, and just really need to get this sorted. I have looked through the files through ftp, and I can't find the cron.php file everywhere seems to be referring too, so i'm completely baffled right now. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or what I can do to find out what the issue is.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong but I can tell you how I set up Magento2 cron on a recent project.

I have been putting files inside the `/etc/cron.d/` folder. This may be specific to certain Linux distributions and may be specific to how a particular Linux box is set up.

But in theory any file inside the `/etc/cron.d/` folder will be run by cron. The syntax is slightly different but this method avoids having to work out which users' crontab to edit.

So:

```
# File : /etc/cron.d/magento2
# Run Magento2 cron every 7 minutes 
*/7 * * * * magento_user php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run
```

[Linux commands* to create the file are
`cd /etc/cron.d/`
`ls -l`
`vim magento2`
]

- `ls -l` will show you the files here already.
- *you might prefer to type `nano magento2` instead of `vim magento2`, `nano` being a slightly more user-friendly editor for those unaccustomed to editing text files in Linux
- please note: add a blank line at the end of this text file after the cron entry so the file ends with an empty line (this may be superstition but there is no harm in it)

To check that cron is running, on the Linux command prompt enter:

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

if that fails (Linux setups vary in where cron logs to) try

`tail -n 100 /var/log/cron`

[if that fails, hit the internet for advice [such as this from Benjamin Cane](http://bencane.com/2011/11/02/did-my-cronjob-run/)]

You should see some log entries from various cron jobs that are running. If you do not see any recent entries then perhaps the Linux cron is not running but I think that would be unusual (and a whole different Q&A).

Eventually you should see a Magento entry in your Linux cron log due to the file you put in `/etc/cron.d/` for example I see this:

`CROND[3196]: (magento_user) CMD (php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run)`

Then the main way I check Magento cron is behaving is to study the Magento database table `cron_schedule` closely (using a tool such as MySQL Workbench).

If the Linux OS cron is calling Magento2 cron then you should see entries in this table with status `pending`. Presently you should see status `complete` or perhaps a useful error message to indicate where the Magento cron failed.

==================================

#### Adendum

I re-read your question.

- `cron.php` is from Magento 1.x so you should ignore any advice related to that
- if you want to log to `<magento install path>/var/log/some-cron-file.log` then you do probably need to create that file first by `cd /full-path-to-magento-install/var/log/`, `ls -l`, `touch some-cron-file.log` and then the harder part: give your new file the correct ownership and permissions for Linux cron to be able to write here. I don't know what they are for you but I know you can work that out. (but you don't really need to make your own log entries, the Linux system will most likely, and can be set to, log cron jobs to `syslog` or a dedicated log file)